# Is $d(xdx)=dx^2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There's a problem in my book that says to find the second-order derivative of $$u=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$

This is what I did
$$d^2u=f''(\sqrt{}x^2+y^2)(\frac{xdx+ydy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})^2+f'(\sqrt{}x^2+y^2)d(\frac{xdx+ydy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$$

$$d(\frac{xdx+ydy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})=\frac{d(xdx+ydy)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-d(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(xdx+ydy)}{x^2+y^2}$$

The result of my book shows that $$d(\frac{xdx+ydy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})=\frac{(ydx-xdy)^2}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}$$

To reach that result I used that $d(xdx)=dx^2$ and I got the same result. But is that equality true? If so why is that?

Comment: Since $dx, dy$ appear in the expression for $z$, it is a differential, not a function of $y, z$.

Comment: Short answer -- no.

Comment: In context I'm guessing that you actually have the vector-valued function $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} e_1 + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} e_2$ where $e_1,e_2$ are the standard basis vectors (you might call them $\hat{i},\hat{j}$ instead). Then you are dotting that with the differential vector $d\mathbf{r}=dx e_1 + dy e_2$. Trying to take the total derivative of a differential doesn't really make sense, but it would make sense to multiply the Jacobian of that vector valued function with $d\mathbf{r}$.

Comment: @Nick then what is it equal to?

Comment: d(xdx)=d(x)dx+d(dx)=(dx)^2+dx^2

Comment: Can you explain more the context in which your question is formulated? For instance, I cannot think of any situation in an ordinary calculus course where one would be taking $d$ of a differential expression. On the other hand, in advanced calculus or more likely differential geometry, one does indeed see differentials of differentials, and the equation in your title would be true when *carefully* interpreted.

Comment: @LeeMosher I tried to explain a bit more

Comment: Probably the question is to get the Hessian matrix of $f$, which is not really the same as what you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

In order to find $$d(xdx)$$ you apply the product rule of differentiation.

$$d(xdx)= dxdx + xd^2x = (dx)^2 + xd^2x$$

Comment: I suggest $(dx)^2$ instead of $dx^2$ which can be misread in this context.

Comment: Does this mean the result on my book is wrong?

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, done.

Comment: @J.Dane The book is correct only if $d^2x=0$

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right path to show
$$  \mathrm{d}\left( \frac{x \,\mathrm{d} x+y \,\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right) = \frac{\left(x^2+y^2\right) (x \,\mathrm{d}^2 x+y \,\mathrm{d}^2 y)+x^2 (\mathrm{d}y)^2+y^2 (\mathrm{d}x)^2-2 x y \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}}  \text{.}  $$

Then 
$$  \frac{(y \,\mathrm{d}x - x \,\mathrm{d}y)^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{x^2 (\mathrm{d}y)^2+y^2 (\mathrm{d}x)^2-2 x y \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}}  \text{.}  $$

To find conditions for these two left hand sides to be equal, we set them equal, then cancel matching terms, and then cancel the $(x^2 + y^2)$ between the numerator and the denominator, leaving
$$  0 = \frac{x \,\mathrm{d}^2 x+y \,\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{1/2}}  \text{.}  $$

Maybe it's unclear what is happening when $x = y = 0$, but away from that point, the denominator is positive, so this requires $x \,\mathrm{d}^2 x+y \,\mathrm{d}^2 y = 0$.  For that to hold for every choice of $x$ and $y$, we must have $\mathrm{d}^2 x = \mathrm{d}^2 y = 0$ (and with that choice, the limit as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ of the right hand side of the previous display becomes zero as well).

Answer (score 0):

If this is related to the differential operator $d$ from differential geometry, then a property of $d$ is that $d(dx) = 0$ and $d(uv) = (du)v + u(dv)$.